# How does the personal/household activity exemption not apply to domestic CCTV pointed to the street?

Tags: united-kingdom, gdpr, privacy

I am surprised to learn that, in the UK, private/domestic CCTV cameras pointed to the public street [make the owner GDPR controller](https://ico.org.uk/your-data-matters/domestic-cctv-systems-guidance-for-people-being-filmed/) — with all the consequences like having to respond to data requests from all those strangers who were filmed.

In Czech Republic though, the [personal/household activity exemption](https://gdpr-info.eu/recitals/no-18/) [<s>applies</s>](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/50972/2682) (edit: no, it does not, my bad).

Was/is it correct for the courts to not apply the exemption? How is filming the street with personal CCTV substantially different from filming it with a phone? (other than for the operator not being visible to the strangers — which makes the first impression for them that nothing is being filmed).

Comment: “In Czech Republic though, the personal/household activity exemption applies.” – I'm not sure we read the same thing. As the answers in the linked question explain, the household exemption was found to NOT apply when public spaces were covered by CCTV surveillance. This is 100% in line with the ICO interpretation. And since the Ryneš judgement was made by the CJEU before Exit Day, it is also relevant for the UK.

Comment: @amon You are right. I am embarrassed for misreading the linked Czech case and so I shall delete this question soon.

Answer (score 9):

### Why do you expect different courts to determine different laws in the same way?

The Czech and UK laws that implement the GDPR are necessary different because they are the products of different legislative and legal traditions and are written in different languages. The differences may be minor but they will exist.

Particular cases will have different factual and legal nuances and be interpreted by different courts with very different judicial traditions.

Czech courts set no precedents in UK courts and vice-versa.

It’s no surprise that there will be different outcomes.

Even jurisdictions with much closer legal traditions like US Federal Circuit Courts and Australian states often have divergent precedents on similar (or the same) legislation.

Comment: "different outcomes" — is there an actual UK case yet, or just what the ICO thinks the outcome should be?

Comment: Answering the question in the title of your answer, GDPR is muuuuch more expected to be applied consistently where it applies (even the UK GDPR which is supposed to mirror the original GDPR) than "_similar (or the same) legislation_" in countries like the US/Australia.

Comment: @Greendrake Yes. https://www.judiciary.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Fairhurst-v-Woodard-Judgment-1.pdf

Comment: That's a very nice case. However, I see the defendant failed to even mention the personal/household activity exemption. Neither did the judge.

Comment: Well, it’s a judgement not a transcript so we can’t tell if this issue was raised or not. It may have been common ground that the household exemption didn’t apply or it may not have been pressed either of which would explain why it’s not in the judgement

Comment: EU directives are implemented as laws in member states. EU regulations just are. So whilst what you are saying is true to some extent, it's less true than under the 1995 Data Protection Directive which it replaced.

Comment: But the result of not mentioning the exemption in the judgment is that should another case like this arise in which the defence of personal/household activity _is_ actively used, the cited case will be distinguished.

Comment: @Greendrake Some questions of law are so well settled that it makes no sense to dispute them in court. The closest thing in Fairhurst v Woodard is in para 32 where the defendant claims that the ICO told him he couldn't register as a data controller, which the court calls “extremely surprising” and “patently wrong”. The ICO would indeed have told him that he didn't have to pay the registration fee, but the court doesn't doubt that the defendant is a controller. This also follows directly from the applicable CJEU precedent in the Rynes case, the Czech case which you mentioned in your question.

Comment: @amon I don't see how that question is settled any better than any other points the defendant tried to argue. If he decided to go though the trial at all, it is very strange that he at least did not try that line of defence. After all, I do not see how CCTV pointed at the street is much different from just filming on the street with a phone.

Answer (score 0):

"in the UK, private/domestic CCTV cameras pointed to the public street make the owner GDPR controller" is not an accurate summary of the law.

[From the ICO Website](https://ico.org.uk/your-data-matters/domestic-cctv-systems-guidance-for-people-being-filmed/), emphasis added:-

"Data protection laws don’t apply if the cameras **cover only the user’s own private property, including their garden**. Therefore, visitors caught on these cameras don’t have specific data protection rights in relation to the images captured on those cameras."

Comment: I don't get what point you're trying to make. Did you see "**pointed to the public street**"? If a camera is pointed to the public street, surely it does not _only_ cover the owner's property, right? It may not even cover private property at all and wholly cover the street.

Comment: I recall there was some trouble with exactly this and the practical idea was to make certain the cameras only covered one's private property (even if this involves masking some of the camera's field of view) to avoid becoming a GDPR controller

Comment: @Greendrake - no these two things are not automatically linked, it very much depends on the size of the property for instance.

Comment: @ti7 The question is asked from the position of an owner who **wants** to monitor the public area on purpose. So your practical idea is slightly out of place.